# MVC Json FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, fullcalendar

I am having a general problem, I used a other guys base to finally get this working and got it working with my database, however when I try to convert it to my project I get an error here is my code:

So I have an index page in the View am using ID Calendar...

I also have an Action inside controller other than Index called -

```
public ActionResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
{
    var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
    var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

    var items = db.NewEvents.Select(a => new ListOfEvents
    {
        title = a.Title,
        start = a.Start,
        end = a.End,
        allDay = a.AllDay,
        date = a.Date,
        url = a.Url
    });

    var eventList = items.ToList();

    var rows = eventList.ToArray();

    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have checked and copied that code from my other project ( which works great btw ) so I know the names are all 100% correct.

This is the Error I get:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null
>   entry for parameter 'start' of non-nullable type 'System.Double' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetEvents(Double, Double)' in
>   'PropertyManager.Areas.Tenant.Controllers.EventController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

I honestly am not sure how to fix as in the other project I dont call it with parameters either. However I do notice in Chrome when I go network view I see start & end and its correct dates etc. They just arent getting passed properly into the controller what should I do ?

Comment: What URL do you see on Network tab? It has to be something wrong with the request, if you say that values are set on client side.

Comment: Yes I can see the problem although the dates are correct ( Start 2014/07/17 I know its wrong as its meant to be in UNIX form but its not.
http://gyazo.com/3c6abe52e8ad21f706dc089d4cee9882.png

And here is the preview:
http://gyazo.com/15168c4611488dd1dd85a171b1bd4d8e.png

I dont understand really I use exact same code in different projects. Could ViewModels cause an issue?

Comment: So the problem is in dates format? Did it solve you problem or you still need help?

Comment: Cant figure it out, I use the exact same code on the other project as its coming from a DB, It just doesnt seem to be calling it correrctly how its setup is I am on the Index page - Just for outputting the calender, then the jQuery is like this :
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: false,

                //defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                editable: false,
                events: "/home/GetEvents/"
            });

As you can see events: /Home/GetEvents/ this goes to the Action GetEvents as you can see in original post... Other project it BP's. Doesnt here

Comment: No space left but here are images of it failing and the other working huge difference...
http://gyazo.com/e630caf8e5f38758a62e6a63745dc9aa.png

http://gyazo.com/b89b9450cbafd8c8fa7d8197e8d01a21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [event as a json feed](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) passes `start` and `end` parameters in ISO8601 format:

> The values of these parameters will be ISO8601 date strings (like 2013-12-01).

What you can do to make this work in unix format is on your client side, replace the `events` property in AJAX call to the following code ([events (as a function)](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/)):

```
...
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/GetEvents/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            start: start.unix(),
            end: end.unix()
        },
        success: function(doc) {
            // The following code is taken from documentation.
            var events = [];
            $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                events.push({
                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                    start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                });
            });
            callback(events);
        }
    });
}
...
```

Comment: I actually got this working without this, however this should work yes. I downloaded a wrong script file and it was the only difference ( the script version ) I seemed to be using a BETA version I switched back to stable normal release and worked instantly.

Thanks so much for your help and the solution though !

Comment: You're welcome. I'm pretty sure that your working script contains similar solution.